# Always empty result when trying to get order details

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

i'm testing my PHP PayPal SDK integration, so i've created an order using my sandbox account and the PayPal Orders API to get the order_id and till now all is good , now when i try to run my php sdk to get the order_id detail i always get an empty response

i've tried many methods but always same problem,

this is my php code

```
$client = PayPalClient::client();

$req = new OrdersGetRequest($order_id);
$req->path = "/v2/checkout/orders/51805630RM7982526";
$response = $client->execute($req);
return $response;
```

when i execute it i get

```
{
    "response": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "result": {},
        "headers": {
            "": "",
            "Date": "Thu, 15 Aug 2019 15",
            "Server": "Apache",
            "paypal-debug-id": "b7f07a65b9b85",
            "HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR": "sandbox.slc",
            "Paypal-Debug-Id": "b7f07a65b9b85",
            "Set-Cookie": "X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00",
            "Vary": "Authorization",
            "Content-Length": "633",
            "Connection": "close",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

status code with 200 but the result is empty :(

Comment: Just a hunch (as I had something similar with the eBay API before), but if you try accessing an expected part of the result, does it still show as blank? **Test this:** echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

Comment: Try this: echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

Comment: ty for u r response , same prblm ( i'm using postman he have it's own json prettier )